# Can I load the full page on controller destroy? Angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to load the full page when going from 1 controller to another. Is that possible to detect in $destroy ?

Comment: `$scope.$on("$destroy", function() { window.reload(); })` Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @devqon I use VideoJS-markers plugin on 2 pages. When I go from one page to another, it gave me errors. It was working only if I refreshed the page. Now I had to change a little the plugin and I fixed it. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the `$destroy` event like any event with `$scope.$on("$destroy")`. Here is an example:

```
module.controller("TestController", function($scope) {    
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        console.log("Destroyed!");
    });
});
```